# Manipulation HTML DOM of Vue3 List Item

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i use vue 3 and i want to manipulate a single list item by button click

this is my html:

```
<socialDiv v-for="(follower, i) in followerList" :key="follower.id" :ref="el => { followerDiv[i] = el }">
<div class="text-md text-gray-800">{{ follower.name }}</div>
<div class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{ follower.username }}</div>
<button @click="handleBtnClick" id="fbtn">{{ follower.btn }}</button>
```

this is my script:

```
<script setup>
const followerDiv = ref({})

function handleBtnClick() {
  console.log(followerDiv.value)
}
</script>
```

this is my output:

[image]

i'm able to access followerDiv.value[0] but i cannot manipulate the item itself as a DOM element.

how can i access the child items as DOM elements?

**Update:**

To access the list items i have to add "$el" after value.

I can access the values via:

followerDiv.value[i].$el.style.background = "red"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can pass index to your function :

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const followerDiv = ref({})
    const followerList = ref([{id: 1, name: 'aa', username: 'aa', btn: 'aa'}, {id: 2, name: 'bb', username: 'bb', btn: 'bb'}])

    function handleBtnClick(i) {
      followerDiv.value[i].style.color = "red"
    }
    return {
      followerList, followerDiv, handleBtnClick
    }
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="(follower, i) in followerList" :key="follower.id" :ref="el => { followerDiv[i] = el }">
    <div class="text-md text-gray-800">{{ follower.name }}</div>
    <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">{{ follower.username }}</div>
    <button @click="handleBtnClick(i)" id="fbtn">{{ follower.btn }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I receive this error message: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')
    at Proxy.handleFollow (index.vue:55:1)
    at onClick (index.vue:135:1).. problem is that i cannot access "followerDiv.value[i].style.color" because it is displayed as "Proxy"

Comment: @pennylane hey mate, I made snippet for you with `script setup`, take a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-ecdni4?file=src%2FApp.vue) pls

Comment: thanks a lot! i found the mistake.. i bind "ref" to a childComponent.. so i have to add  "$el" after value.. in my case this will work: followerDiv.value[i].$el.style.color = "red".. thanks a lot for your example!